# Executing shell script using docker file

Tags: python, bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I have some tar files which I want to move to docker image and extract them there and then run python web app script. I have sh script that extracts those files.

If I run the script using RUN command then they get extracted but they are not present in the final container.

I also used entrypoint but it executes and then closes container not executing "main python script".

Is there a way how to execute this install script and then continue running the main script and not closing?

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && npm install -g bower \
    && npm install -g gulp@^3.9.1

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && npm install \
    && bower install --allow-root \
    && gulp default

# Define environment variable
ENV PATH "$PATH:/app/tree-tagger/cmd/"
ENV PATH "$PATH:/app/tree-tagger/bin/"
ENV TREETAGGER "/app/tree-tagger/cmd/"
ENV TREETAGGER_HOME "/app/tree-tagger/cmd/"

CMD python app.py

ENTRYPOINT sh tree-tagger/install-tagger.sh
```

Here is docker-compose script on top of that

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:3.0.2
```

Comment: when you have an entrypoint that should start something and keep running, but your docker container exits immediately instead, that something has problem to run. to debug it you can run the container with manually overriden --entrypoint=/bin/bash and try to run your command by hand to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use RUN for that. RUN runs on container side so anything new that gets created by it - will be included in container as well.

Your issue most likely comes from the fact that your docker-compose file is mounting a volume that you previously wrote to.
Basically, what you're trying to do is:
1. During container creation, copy current dir to /app and do something with it
2. After container is created - run it while mounting current dir to /app again.

So you end up with anything newly created in /app/ to be overwritten. If you skip the volume part in docker-compose, it will all work as expected. But if you prefer to mount current app code to /app anyway (so you don't have to rebuild image during development every time your code change), there is a way. Just change your docker-compose to:

```
web:
  build: .
   ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
    - /app/tree-tagger/
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:3.0.2
```

Now you can just change your dockerfile to what you had before (with RUN instead of ENTRYPOINT) and /app/tree-tagger/ won't be replaced this time. So:

```
...  
RUN sh tree-tagger/install-tagger.sh
CMD python app.py
```